# How To Trigger Button Click on Enter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, triggers, enter

The addEventListener on click is working but on *event.keypress* or *event.code* dont.
I can't understand why?
I tried to add key code, with and without "", tried to remove default, with indication of object length (inputLength() > 0 && event.code "Enter") etc.. still nothing.
Can't find a solution in existent threads((.

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");


function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
})

button.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        createListElement();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing "keyup" to "keypress":

```
button.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        createListElement();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
button.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    //now do what you want to do.
    createListElement();  
}
} false);
```

I just want to say, that you should definetly use google more often. I was able to find the anwser after 1 google search. Anyways hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answ. i tried it already, it dont work because event.keyCode is deprecated and how i mentioned before with other (event.keypress or event.code ) still dont work.

Comment: try `event.key === 'Enter'`, and also do what the guy said above me, put false before the last bracket in the addEventListener.@m

Answer (score 1):

For addEventListener, you may need a third argument false
e.g. button.addEventListener("click",function(){blah},false);

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way:

```
function addListAfterKeyPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.key === "Enter") {
        createListElement();
    }
}
```